# Core Data fetchedresultscontroller returns empty on device only

Tags: ios, core-data, device, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I Wrote an application that uses core data and it was working fine, on both simulator and devices. Then I made a new git branch of the project and it works perfectly on the simulator but not on the devices.

Here is the code for the `fetchedResultsController`

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Fetched Controler : %@", _fetchedResultsController);
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Membership" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userdata.email == %@",    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"email"]];    
    NSSortDescriptor *sort1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"type" ascending:NO];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"membership_name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sort1,sort2, nil];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"type" cacheName:nil];
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Then I fetch the objects in view will apear.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSError *error;
    [[self fetchedResultsController]performFetch:&error];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The `managed object context` is passed from `appDelegate` to the login view then from the loginView to the second view. On the second view is where I am having problems

The only thing that I can think of is that something is happening with the memory limitations on the device or maybe a concurrency issue?
If there are are any threads created I did not mean to do it.

Comment: You can check if the second view is on different thread with:
NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread currentThread]);

Comment: have you set the email in the user defaults?

Comment: Thank you user523234 it didn't help in this case but That was part of my question and I will definitely use that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your predicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = 
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userdata.email == %@",    
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"email"]];
```

is returning an empty set. Log the value of this user default and I am convinced this will be cleared up.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! The nsuserdefault was case sensitive.